# How do I select multiple values with one checkbox?

Tags: search

With Facets module/search API, I have a checkbox filter where I need to merge some value.

Example:

```
vocabulary  = color

term = light red

term = dark red

term = light blue

term = dark blue
```

In this case i have 4 checkbox.

My checkbox should look like this

```
vocabulary  = color

term = red

term = blue
```

And When i tick Red it list all content tagged with dark red and light red
And When i tick blue it list all content tagged with  dark blue and light blue

thus the parent term will not be a used value in the filtered content, but only the child value will filter the content.

**Question :** Is it possible to do that with taxonomy hierachy option in the facets?

Comment: Are red and blue actual terms in your vocabulary, where light red and dark red are children of a parent term, red?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this with by activating 'index Hierarchy" in the Search API processor configuration page with the proper taxonomy selected. in the taxonomy i've created new parent term and putted the childs in it, then in the facets those parent are displayed - in a checkbox in my case - and when selecting those parent it filter the content with the value of all the childs.
Note that I've excludes the display of the childs in the checkbox, in the facets properties.